# Centos - terminal creates directories/files with no owner/group?

Tags: linux, centos, shell, terminal, cpanel

I'm very new to server admin. I'm having an issue whereby any file or folder I create via the terminal on WHM (Centos 7.6) results in a file/folder with 0/0 user and group stat.

Example command:

```
mkdir mydir
```

This is confirmed in Filezilla, and consequently none of the files load in the browser - I get a 500 error.

This doesn't happen when I create files/dirs directly within FileZilla. What can I do to address this?

---

[EDIT]

In response to Thomas' comment, the output for `ls -alh mydir` is:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  6 Aug  1 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 dev  dev  18 Aug  1 18:23 ..
```

while the output for `ls -alh <file created earlier, not via terminal>` is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 gcore gcore 9.6K Nov 28  2018 index.php
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -alh mydir` and `ls -alh <file-created-by-filezilla`. Looks like you are creating files/folders as `root` but use a different user when connecting via FileZilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the folder `mydir` as user `root`, files and folders are created with owner and group of `root`.

You could either

---

Change the owner and group afterwards by

```
chown gcore:gcore mydir
```

Or if the folder contains files you want to use `chown` as follows to recursively change owner/group.

```
chown -R gcore:gcore mydir
```

---

Change to the user `gcore` and create things then

```
sudo -u gcore -i
```

or

```
su - gcore
```

---

Use `sudo` on every command

```
sudo -u gcore mkdir mydir
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem.

Comment: Actually... while this did result in directories being created WITH users/groups, I'm still getting 500 when I try to run any files created inside of it (whether created via terminal or FZ.) Any thoughts?

Comment: @Utkanos: I think best would be to open another question on the 500 error.